# OpenLayers OSM layer

Tags: openlayers-2, openstreetmap, javascript

I need to define an layer in OpenLayers just showing world map. The most simpliest variant is to create OSM layer. When I do like this:

```
var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("OSM");
map.addLayer(layer);
```

How can I define restrictions/bounds to show the world map?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add restrictions to whole map and change its later (if necessary), for example:

```
var map, layer;
function init() {
    map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {
        maxExtent: [-18924313.432222, -15538711.094146, 18924313.432222, 15538711.094146],
        restrictedExtent: [-13358338.893333, -9608371.5085962, 13358338.893333, 9608371.5085962],
    });
    layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("Simple OSM Map");
    map.addLayer(layer);
}
```

See also:

- http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/osm.html
- http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/restricted-extent.html